# jQuery image hover not working on Firefox, when I uploaded files to online server

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, firefox

It was working fine on Firefox on local machine but when I uploaded the files online it just stopped animating and showing a static image.

[View it here](http://shikeb.izihost.org/New/)

The Javascript I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("ul.gallery li").hover(function() { //On hover...

    var thumbOver = $(this).find("img").attr("src"); //Get image url and assign it to 'thumbOver'

    //Set a background image(thumbOver) on the <a> tag - Set position to bottom
    $(this).find("a.thumb").css({'background' : 'url(' + thumbOver + ') no-repeat center bottom'});

    //Animate the image to 0 opacity (fade it out)
    $(this).find("span").stop().fadeTo('normal', 0 , function() {
        $(this).hide() //Hide the image after fade
    });
} , function() { //on hover out...
    //Fade the image to full opacity 
    $(this).find("span").stop().fadeTo('normal', 1).show();
});

});</script>
```

any idea why its happening !
Solution ??

Comment: You're loading jquery twice.. would that be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Correction: After looking at your site, it appears that your images are not located where you are looking.

Instead of:

```
../images/gthumb01.png
```

change it to:

```
/images/gthumb01.png
```

Because your images are located in the `/New/images/` directory

http://shikeb.izihost.org/New/images/gthumb01.png

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your page, I see the images try to swap, then swap back almost immediately.  It looks like you're having the second function of the .hover() being called as the image is swapping.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is interesting, if you remove the ad bit at the end of the page:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">[...]</div>
```

Then it works fine.

You can try it live in firebug..

EDIT: re-actually, if you just delete the image in the ad and leave the wrapping it works too...

Comment: no i dint added any ad, I'm testing on a free server thats coming from them ... not in my control.

Comment: I understand, but it seems the ad, or whatever is injecting it is somewhat responsible. If you delete the element in firebug then suddenly everything works fine.